# Prevent iOS URL scheme hijack

Tags: ios, security, ios9, url-scheme

I have an app that gets opened from another app via a URL scheme. The URL contains signup tokens. As any app can register the same URL scheme as my app, I am concerned a "fake" app can do a man-in-the-middle attack and capture the signup tokens.

My idea is to check that the URL scheme does not open another app when my app is first opened.

From a security perspective, if the URL scheme opens my app the first time, will it always open my app in the future?

Answer (score 5):

How about using iOS 9 universal links?

> Unlike custom URL schemes, universal links can’t be claimed by other apps, because they use standard HTTP or HTTPS links to your website.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

This way the "dispatch table" is on your server, so no other app can hijack the signup URL. (URL dispatch is based on AppIDs)

Answer (score 2):

It's a valid (and usually ignored) attack vector. It isn't strictly a man-in-the-middle attack as it won't forward the URL on to your app (it can't). It's almost worse as the attacking app would only really be able to crash and it would look like your app had...

Another app could be installed any time your app is in the background. Technically it's possible that an update is released and installed for an existing app while your app is running (it's hard to know if that happens). So, it isn't safe to only test when your app is first opened.

Comment: Isn't the URL scheme a "first come, first served" scheme?

Comment: I'm not 100% what the rule is, I haven't explicitly tested it. It'll either be first installed or last installed. Hence one app can't forward to the other.

Comment: As per https://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/ios-url-scheme-susceptible-to-hijacking/, it is first-come-first-serve on iOS 11 and above